# Resetting a Stored Procedure variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

Well, apparently this does not work. I get a "incorrect syntax near '='" error.
Is it possible to change the value of a variable several times within a stored procedure?

Similar to this example :

```
    DECLARE @columnCounter INT
    SET @columnCounter = 0

    DECLARE @columnName VARCHAR(255)
    SET @columnName = 'A'

    WHILE (@columnCounter < 4)
    BEGIN
        IF (@columnCounter == 1)
        BEGIN
            SET @columnName = 'B'
        END
        IF (@columnCounter == 2)
        BEGIN
            SET @columnName = 'C'
        END
        IF (@columnCounter == 3)
        BEGIN
            SET @columnName = 'D'
        END
    END
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the [`==`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175118%28v=sql.100%29.aspx). Transact-SQL uses simple `=` for equality comparison, like this:

```
DECLARE @columnCounter INT;
SET @columnCounter = 0;

DECLARE @columnName VARCHAR(255);
SET @columnName = 'Set_To_Value_ID';

WHILE (@columnCounter < 4)
BEGIN
    IF (@columnCounter = 1)
    BEGIN
        SET @columnName = 'Set_To_Variable_ID';
    END
    IF (@columnCounter = 2)
    BEGIN
        SET @columnName = 'Changed_In_SP';
    END
    IF (@columnCounter = 3)
    BEGIN
        SET @columnName = 'Set_To_Comment_Input';
    END
    set @columnCounter += 1;
END
```

Answer (score 1):

```
IF (@columnCounter == 1)
```

Comparison there should just be `=`, `==` is a common syntax in a number of languages, but not t-sql.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175118(v=sql.100).aspx